# Why is getBoundingClientRect slow in IE8?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8

I'm using IE9, put into IE8 standards mode using F12 tools, to test my page. The page script uses `getBoundingClientRect` to work out what's visible in the viewport.

Using the profiling tool, I'm seeing calls to `getBoundingClientRect` taking a lot of time. For example, 244 calls to the function took an exclusive time of 4,361ms!

Is there a reason for this function being so slow in IE8? When running in IE9 mode, Chrome, FireFox, etc, the function seems fast.

Comment: Each call of it might trigger a DOM reflow, depending on how and where you use it?

Answer (score 0):

The [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) was first introduced by Microsoft in IE5, and there no known performance issues.

jQuery UI, and others, use it and when in the past they move to it, was awesome: http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

I found a compare between `jQuery similar calculation` and `getBoundingClientRect`:
http://jsperf.com/getboundingclientrect-vs-jquery
usually win getBoundingClientRect

You are running your site in IE8 compatibility mode that sometimes can uglify performances, can you test it in a real IE8 browser? Here performance must be the same.

Comment: I'm going to get an IE8 VM set up later this week and test. I'm hoping it is just the compat mode being slow.

Comment: @AndrewDavey I am running into the same problem - did you find out if the performance issues are only a side-effect of the compatibility mode?

Comment: @AndrewDavey have tested on the real IE8. Performance is poor as hell. Aside, it's relatively poor in other browsers too if you do a lot of calls, even in Chrome and IE11. IE11 is slower than Chrome, almost like the IE8.